# change root folder on hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, hosting

hello
i want to change root folder, for example root is:
http://mydonmain/

but now i want to create a folder inside of root and want this folder to be root, so

http://mydomain/myroot/

Is now my new root but if i click a link i get:
http://mydomain/myroot/mypage.php

but i would still want :
http://mydomain/mypage.php   (all this with my new root folder)

is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the a tag you are using?

If you set the href to say "/mypage.php" rather than "mypage.php" it should goto "http://mydomain/mypage.php".

Also you could use mod_rewrite and put something like this:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myroot/$1 [PT,L,QSA]

Comment: whith the / in the <a> the links look like i want in the bottom of the browser, but i get a 404 error

Comment: You will get a 404 as the page doesn't exist there anymore it now exists in /myroot so you would have to rewrite the url in apache to change it.